# Put a formula in excel chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts, textbox

I want to fill a text box on an Excel chart using VBA.  I tried this:

```
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Shapes(1).Formula = "Sheet1!A1"
```

and it doesn't work, but this does:

```
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.Shapes(1).Select
 Selection.Formula = "=Sheet1!A1"
```

There probably is something I need to put between `Shapes(1)` and `.Formula`, but I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Note that the second formula (the one that works) includes an equals sign before the sheet name:

"=Sheet1!A1"

while the first does not:

"Sheet1!A1"

Comment: Thank you for answering. This code was simplified.  When I make sure to include the "=" sign in the first example, it still doesn't work. My thought was that selecting the shape establishes a new level of object that can accept the formula, but the direct code in the first formula doesn't do that.

Comment: Apparently this part of the OM was broken in the "upgrade" from Excel 2003 to 2007. I don't know how to apply a formula to a shape (embedded in a chart or just in a sheet) without selecting it first.

Comment: In XL2010, using `.TextFrame.Characters.Parent.Formula` does the trick. By the way the `TypeName` of `.TextFrame.Characters.Parent` is `TextBox` but you cannot refer directly to `.Formula` in the textbox context directly ... weird.

Comment: and to complete my previous comment, actually you can access textboxes and their `.Formula` property through `ActiveChart.TextBoxes` collection (not mentionned in the Object members ...).
[Found this tip here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?17650-Assign-Formula-to-Chart-Sheet-Text-Box-%28migrating-from-Excel-2003-to-Excel-2007%29)